Unable to locate package python-gobject in Debian 12 Bookworm
I am trying to have touchpad gestures on my Debian.......while writing commands.....it is in this section of command where I start facing problem
~
sudo apt-get install wmctrl python3 python3-setuptools xdotool python3-gi libinput-tools python-gobject
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-gobject
~
I was expecting to go with this command uniterrupted and then I would have gone to install libinput gestures.

debian package names starting with python- are either dummy packages or python2 ones. rarely useful. in your case it's python2. the pygobject doc says the good way is:
sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-4.0


Thanks for helping me but the problem still persists. [link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zSWlY9MmfRIL0Ex0-Pkj1Jzw7mHGtK9c/view?usp=sharing

no external links please. and update your question

Thanks and sorry, now I know how to insert an image into my question itself from my local device and I have edited some portions in my question. Thank you.
